# Div Attached to side of wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a div to the side of my wrapper. It will be a link / button.

I want it to be able to slide up and down, fixed to the right hand side border when scrolling.

The button is:

```
#booknow {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
margin-left:25px;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
font-size:22px;
color:#ffffff!important;
font-weight:700;
line-height:26px!important;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

And the inner wrapper (Where the border is), is:

```
.wrapper_inner{
position:relative;
z-index:10!important;
padding:30px!important; 
background:#fff!important;
border:1px solid #D4D4D4!important; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper_inner">
    <div id="booknow">
      <a href="booknow"> Book <br> Now </a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

At the minute I have this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9YyuAzW.png]

If I set it to fixed it slides up and down but it won't position perfectly to the outside of .wrapper_inner.

Comment: Can you share all of your relevant code, including HTML please?

Comment: It wont let me add code in nicely.. This is the basic structure: http://pastebin.com/u0UydWYw - The booknow button is inside inside_wrapper, wrapper is full width.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML wasn't that helpful, so I just threw something together. The color scheme is to display the elements. I removed `.inner_wrapper` and added the surrounding layout so it would be possible to demonstrate that `#booknow` floats. If you click the `#booknow` it'll scroll down to a faux form at the bottom.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/qACqW4O4rJn7YHoPRWLy?p=preview

Full screen: https://run.plnkr.co/njw73AIIIuHXEooM/

### Relevant CSS

```
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  font: 500 16px/1.4 'Arial';
  min-height: 100vh;

}

.spacer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -200px;
  height: 60%;
}

#booknow {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fc3;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: -110px;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px double grey;
  min-height: 70px;
  background: #eff999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just floats to the right of the page. I need it to be attached to the side of .inner_wrapper so it is on the border.

Comment: I just need to find a way to stick / float a div to the right of another. So it is touching, then it scrolls up and down with the page.

Comment: This div that's to the left of `#booknow` moves with it?

Comment: Anyways, here's an update, but I'm not doing any more until I see an example with substantial code namely HTML. http://plnkr.co/edit/KLoOPDj3BJPO2k0BYXou?p=preview